# How to prevent appending data to an existing cell on drag drop of table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop

I am dragging and dropping a table view cell. But it shows a plus icon when on top of a cell and if I drop, the text gets appended. How to prevent this plus icon and append behaviour and just allow to reorder?

```
extension CheckListTableViewController: UITableViewDragDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        if let item = self.boardMan.getCheckListItem(indexPath: indexPath) {
            if let stringData = item.title.data(using: .utf8) {
                let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(item: stringData as NSData, typeIdentifier: kUTTypePlainText as String)
                let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
                dragItem.localObject = (item, indexPath, tableView)
                return [dragItem]
            }
        }
        return []
    }
```

```
extension CheckListTableViewController: UITableViewDropDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
        if coordinator.session.hasItemsConforming(toTypeIdentifiers: [kUTTypePlainText as String]) {
            coordinator.session.loadObjects(ofClass: NSString.self) { (items) in
                switch (coordinator.items.first?.sourceIndexPath, coordinator.destinationIndexPath) {
                case (.some(let sourceIndexPath), .some(let destinationIndexPath)):
                    Log.debug("src: \(sourceIndexPath) dest: \(destinationIndexPath)")
                    let updatedIndexPaths: [IndexPath]
                    if sourceIndexPath.row < destinationIndexPath.row {
                        updatedIndexPaths =  (sourceIndexPath.row...destinationIndexPath.row).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
                    } else if sourceIndexPath.row > destinationIndexPath.row {
                        updatedIndexPaths =  (destinationIndexPath.row...sourceIndexPath.row).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
                    } else {
                        updatedIndexPaths = []
                    }
                    if let checkListItem = self.utils.getCheckListItem(indexPath: sourceIndexPath) {
                        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                        _ = self.utils.removeCheckListItem(indexPath: sourceIndexPath)
                        _ = self.utils.insertCheckListItem(checkListItem, indexPath: destinationIndexPath)
                        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: updatedIndexPaths, with: .none)
                        self.tableView.endUpdates()
                    }
                default:
                    Log.debug("default case")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UITableViewDropProposal {
        if tableView.hasActiveDrag {
            return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
        }
        return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .forbidden)
    }
}
```

The table view has drag drop delegates set and has swipe guestures added.

```
self.tableView.dragDelegate = self
self.tableView.dropDelegate = self
self.tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
```

Please see the screenshot below.

[image: snap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to support drag and drop only for the purpose of reordering rows, then you don't need any of the code you posted.

Implement the normal "reorder" related methods of UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate. Set the table's `dragDelegate` and `dropDelegate`. You only need to implement one method each from UITableViewDragDelegate and UITableViewDropDelegate and their implementations are trivial.

For a simple one-section table view all you need is the following:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Update your data model array to move the item at sourceIndexPath.row to destinationIndexPath.row
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDragDelegate

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    return []
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDropDelegate

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
    // no-op
}
```

Make sure you set the table view's `dragDelegate` and `dropDelegate` properties to `self` in `viewDidLoad` or in the storyboard. You also need to turn on the `dragInteractionEnabled` property.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.dragDelegate = self
    self.tableView.dropDelegate = self
    self.tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

That's all you need to support row reordering using drag and drop. Of course for complicated data models and multiple sections, you may need to also implement the `targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt` delegate method and your logic in `moveRowAt` may need further logic.

---

What's interesting is that the need to set the `dropDelegate` and to enable the `dragInteractionEnabled` is only needed for iPhones. The iPad (and Mac Catalyst) version does not need those set.

Comment: In this case, I am able to drag, but not drop. The `moveRowAt` method is not being called.

Comment: It's working for me in the simple test app I used for this answer. What version of Xcode and iOS are you testing with?

Comment: I am using `Xcode Version 11.2 (11B52)` and `iPhone 11 Pro Max 13.2` simulator.

Comment: Strange. On an iPad simulator it works fine but on the iPhone sim my test project isn't allowing drag and drop reordering at all. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: I got it working. I set the `dropDelegate` with an empty implementation and the move works without the plus showing up. Thanks.

Comment: Updated with the additional needs to make it work on the iPhone versus the iPad.

Comment: @rmaddy OMG! I wish I stumbled on your answer first! I spent days upon days trying to do a reordering of the table rows, and I went down the rabbit hole of making my model conform to NSObject, Codable, NSItemProviderWriting, and NSItemProviderReading and all that stuff. Little did I know that it would be this simple. Ugh!